# php Array_push not working in a function

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop that calls a function from an array_push but I get an error:

> $product_export_array is empty

```
$product_export_array = array();
$_ProductIds = array('0','1', '2', '3');

function addProduct ($product_data, $sku_for_product) {
    array_push($product_export_array, array('sku' => $sku_for_product,);
}

foreach ($_ProductIds as $key=>$_product) {
    $simple_sku = 'abc' . $product;
    addProduct($_product, $simple_sku);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it as reference (function argument starts with &, '&$xxx'):

```
$product_export_array = array();
$_ProductIds = array('0','1', '2', '3');

foreach ($_ProductIds as $key=>$product) {
    $simple_sku = 'abc';
    addProduct($product, $simple_sku, $product_export_array);
}

function addProduct ($product_data, $sku_for_product, &$export) {
    array_push($export, array('sku' => $sku_for_product));
}
var_dump($product_export_array);
```

Then elements added in function will be visible in code where you call function.

Comment: It's working too, and by your comment in the other response, it seems a better solution

Comment: [Passing by Reference - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)